# How should a Haskell command line script report errors from `read`?

Tags: haskell, error-handling, command-line-interface, user-experience

I'm uncertain about the correct way to report errors from `read` creating an instance in response to user input at the command line within a `main = do ...`.

Specifically, I have a [constructor](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/blob/develop/Crypto/Enigma.hs#L312) that validates its arguments and reports an error in the usual way

```
-- ...
Right cfg  -> cfg
Left err -> error (show err)
```

and an implementation of `read` that uses this constructor. However inside my implementation I have a [cryptic note](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/blob/develop/Crypto/Enigma.hs#L368) (inherited from some long-ago research that I've since lost track of) that removes error information

```
instance Read ... where
        readsPrec _ i = case ...
            Right cfg  -> [(cfg, "")]
            Left _ -> [] -- Loses error information, but conforms to specification of 'readsPrec' in 'Read'
```

so that [my command line parser](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/blob/new/cli/enigma.hs)

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    ... read
```

reports all errors generated by the constructor as merely

```
Prelude.read: no parse
```

If I ignore my cryptic comment and [instead have](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/blob/new/cli/Crypto/Enigma.hs#L370)

```
Left err -> error (show err)
```

in the constructor, then I get complete error information reported to the user:

```
script: Detailed error information here
  CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at ./Pkg/Module.hs:371:57 in main:Pkg.Module
```

(though with stack and line information I'd rather not report in this context).

So I have three related questions about this:

1. Is there actually any reason not to report full error information from `read` using `Left err -> error (show err)`?
2. If so and something like `Left err -> []` is required there, how do I report `read` or constructor errors at the command line?

and (not as important)

3. How do i get rid of the line an stack information when reporting from `read` in my `main = do ...`?

Comment: Why do you use `Encode { config :: String, message :: String }` rather than `{ config :: EnigmaConfig, ... }`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout: That's for command dispatch, which expects strings entered on the command line, no? How would I enter an `EnigmaConfig` on the command line (in a usable way)?

Comment: Well, through a suitable parser, which seems to be what you want anyways.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: The command line syntax is as [in the examples](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/blob/new/cli/enigma.hs#L72): the config is specified as a string. Read, mostly through the constructor, should handle all the parsing and validation.

Comment: Don't you think _the **parser**_ should handle all the **parsing** and validation?

Comment: @leftaroundabout: The constructor already handles much of it, why write it again? Anyway, what does any of this have to do with the question? If you've got an answer to the question, please suggest one.

Comment: Not sure what you even mean by “the constructor”. At any rate the `instance {Show/Read} EnigmaConfig` aren't really a well-behaved implementations anyway, since `show` should yield _Haskell code_. The proper thing to do is implement a proper parser, and using the error features of the parser-combinator library rather than `Read` which does not support proper error handling.

Comment: Anyone else — please!

Comment: Well, you ask “how do I report `read` or constructor errors at the command line”. The probably most sensible answer is, by _properly using_ the command-line parser, instead of _circumventing the command line parser_ (as you do, by giving an excessively weak type to its result). That is, unless you have a well-founded reason for making it `Encode { config :: String ... }`, but this isn't evident from the question, hence my comment.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Like is said, if there's an answer lurking there somewhere, I'd love to see it. (Again.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes: pure code cannot catch `error` calls. It is frequently useful to know from pure code that `read` (well, `reads`) has failed.
2. Use a different class than `Read` for parsing that lets you report errors more clearly. Each of the popular parser-combinator libraries have facilities for good error reporting.
3. Use the imaginatively-named `errorWithoutStackTrace`.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Right now I simply have the [constructor](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/blob/develop/Crypto/Enigma.hs#L312) validate. That gives me error checking for uses other than `read`. But if I can't pass errors detected there through `read` (e.g. I should restore `Left err -> []` there) it's not clear to me how to make use of that validation and error reporting when instantiating based on a supplied string (which is what `read` does, and what I need from the command line).

Comment: Is it just that I should effectively take the implementation I now have in `read`, put that in a different "reading" function (instantiating one the parser-combinator libraries' classes, that can propagate errors) and use that when reading from the command line; and then just call that new function from `read` (not propagating errors there)?

Comment: @orome I haven't clicked any of your links, and don't plan to. If you have a question which is about the combination of your `read` implementation and some other validation code, you should produce a minimal example and include it in a fresh question.

Comment: So (1) definitely have errors in `read` return `[]` and since that means `read` is not useful for reporting error info, (2) write a new "read-like" function to report errors and use that when instantiating based on CLI input, which (3) can be reported using `errorWithoutStackTrace `.?

Comment: (Sketching out a simple version of that [that function](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/blob/new/cli/Crypto/Enigma.hs#L335) and [using it in the CLI](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/blob/new/cli/enigma.hs#L69) certainly behaves the way I'd like it too, but I'm still not sure that I've got the Haskell error reporting idiom right.)